# Tuning Lucene indexing performance in infinispan

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm using hibernate search and lucene index in infinispan. But the time for indexing is too long.

I'm trying to optimize the performance of indexing with tuning options.

I.e, set `hibernate.search.​[default|<indexname>].​indexwriter.ram_buffer_size` to `64MB`.

I dont know how to set it in Infinispan, can someone give me a example for this solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this configuration, it is taken from upstream and should be optimized. However, I don't know which version of Infinispan are you using, this was for 6.x. The issue with indexing and queries is that performance is very configuration sensitive and it may took some time to tune it properly for your use case.

https://github.com/tsykora/infinispan-odata-server/blob/master/src/main/resources/indexing-perf.xml

Comment: Ty, that really help me a lot. I tried modify parameter **merge_factor** and **max_merge_docs**, but it seems blocked when I add data to cache. Do u have any idea??

Comment: Np, glad to help! Chmmmm, hard to say, would you mind to join #infinispan channel on freenode, IRC? You should talk with anistor or sannegrinovero there. Or maybe better to send message on our mailing list: infinispan-dev@lists.jboss.org and describe your problem. I am sure developers will try to help you.